# Control not going into success block parse.com

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In below code, control is not going on bookinQuery success block. How to use nesting of find in Parse.com ?can someone help? Thanks.

Parse.Cloud.define("checkAvailibilityOfRooms",function(request,response)
    {

```
var bookdate    = request.params.bookdate;
var reqfromtime = request.params.reqfromtime;
var reqtotime   = request.params.reqtotime;


var intervals = 48;  //Total intervals in a day for Booking 
var _in, _out, flag=true;

var room_list = []; 

var RoomObj      = Parse.Object.extend("Room");
var roomQuery    = new Parse.Query(RoomObj); 

roomQuery.find({

    success:function(results){

        for(var i=0 ; i<results.length;i++){

            room_list.push(results[i].get('room_mac_id'));
        }


         console.log(room_list[1]);

          var BookObj      = Parse.Object.extend("Booking");
          var bookingQuery = new Parse.Query(BookObj);

          for(var j=0 ; j<room_list.length;j++){

              console.log("Inside j loop");

                bookingQuery.equalTo("book_date",bookdate);
                bookingQuery.equalTo("room_mac_id",room_list[j]);
                bookingQuery.ascending("book_fromtime");

                bookingQuery.find({

                     success:function(results){

                                console.log("Inside second successs");

                                 var map = [];

                                 for(var i=0;i<intervals;i++){
                                     map.push({index: i, flag: true});
                                 }

                                 console.log(map[0]);
                                 console.log(results[0].get('book_fromtime'));


                                 for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                                     _in = Math.ceil(results[i].get('book_fromtime') * 2);
                                     _out = Math.ceil(results[i].get('book_totime') * 2) - 1;


                                     for(var j=_in;j<=_out;j++){
                                         map[j].flag = false;
                                     }
                                 }


                                 _in = Math.ceil(reqfromtime * 2);
                                 _out = Math.ceil(reqtotime * 2) - 1;

                                 for(var i=_in;i<=_out;i++){

                                     if(!map[i].flag){
                                         flag=false;
                                         break;
                                     }
                                 }

                                 console.log("Status of booking");
                                 console.log(flag);

                     },

                    error:function(error){


                    }

                });//bookingQuery find block



     }



           response.success("Exclude rooms inside");
    },//success block

    error:function(error){

        response.success(error.code + error.message);
 }



}) ;
```

});

Comment: @tushar it is open source.Many are building same using open source parse server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it that I used different syntax of query, I dont know how it happened but changing to this syntax is the only thing that worked for me on my own parse-server...

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Comment', function(request, response) {
   var postID = request.object.get("post_id").id;
   console.log("PostID: " + postID);
   var query = new Parse.Query('Post');
   query.equalTo("objectId", postID);
   query.first({ useMasterKey: true }).then((result) => {
      console.log('query succeeded', result);
      result.increment("commentCount"); 
      result.save();
      response.success();
   }, (error) => {
      console.log('query failed', error);
      response.error(error);
   });
});
```